# prevent duplicate entries

Tags: php, mysql, database

Basically it look through the mp3 files in the folder and then `insert` into mysql database if `number` does not exist.

Problem is `INSERT` (mysql) has been inserted more than 1 time but with different `member_id`'s with same `number`. This shouldn't happen.

4 staffs are executing this scripts. What causing this and how to fix?

```
if ($handle = opendir($audioPath)) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        $file = pathinfo($entry);
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != ".." && !is_dir($audioPath . "/" . $entry) && $file['extension'] == 'mp3') {
            $number = $file['filename'];
            $SQL = "SELECT mobile, status, member_id, count(*) as Total from result WHERE number = :number";
            $query = $this->db->prepare($SQL);
            $query->bindValue(":number", $number);
            $query->execute();

            $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            // Check if number is exist in the table
            if ($row['Total'] == 0) {
                $SQL = "INSERT INTO result (number, status, status_date, member_id) VALUES ('$number', 'pending', now(), '$memberId')";
                $queryInsert = $this->db->prepare($SQL);
                $queryInsert->execute();
                break;
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

after `break` it play mp3 via media player plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably running into a race condition where two people execute the script simultaneously. When the select is performed, the entry does not exist.

The best way to solve this is to add a UNIQUE constraint on your number field in MySQL. This will make sure the condition is matched at insertion. The query will fail, so you will need to handle the error.

Comment: Ahh I see, I see what you mean. I think I have to delete all the duplicate `numbers` before adding UNIQUE?  and it should it be like `INGORE INSERT` ?

Comment: Yes, you will need to clean-up the database before adding the constraint. In your case, INSERT IGNORE should do.

Answer (score 0):

Your first select query should filter on the member ID as well...

```
$SQL = "SELECT mobile, status, member_id, count(*) as Total from result WHERE number = :number AND member_id = :memberid";
```